# Upload multiple files with Javascript Diemensions Validations

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

I want to upload multiple files using PHP with multiple input, also I have used Javascript dimensions validation. The problem is that PHP receive only one file. I want all the files which accept Javascript code should be sent.

Here is my html and Javascript code:

HTML:

```
<input name="gig-images[]" accept="image/*" type="file" multiple id="fileee">
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('#fileee').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var files = this.files;

    var imageBox = document.querySelector('.gig-images-box .box-body');
    var imageBoxFooter = $('.gig-images-box .box-footer');

    //  $('.gig-images-box .box-body').find('img.new_up').remove();


    if (files.length > 0) {
        var img_valid_arr = [];
        imageBoxFooter.html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var load_img = new Image();
            load_img.onload = function () {
                var height = this.height;
                var width = this.width;
                if (width == 750 && height == 350) {
                    var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
                    imgElement.className = 'meriimage new_up';
                    imgElement.height = 60;
                    imgElement.src = this.src;
                    imgElement.onload = function () {
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(imgElement.src);
                    };
                    imageBox.appendChild(imgElement);
                } else {
                    img_valid_arr.push('not valid');
                }

                var sub = files.length - img_valid_arr.length;

                console.log(sub);

                var selc_cont = (sub == 0) ? '<p>No image selected.</p>' : '<p>' + sub + ' image selected.</p>';

                if (img_valid_arr.length > 0) {
                    imageBoxFooter.append(selc_cont);
                    $('.image-title').append('<span class="help-block" style="color:#ff0000; font-size:12px; display:inline-block">The image dimensions should be: 750 width and 350 height</span>');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.help-block').fadeOut();
                    }, 3000);
                } else {
                    imageBoxFooter.html(selc_cont);
                }
            };
            load_img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
        }
    } else {
        imageBoxFooter.html('');
        imageBoxFooter.html('<p>No image selected.</p>');
    }
});
```

PHP Code:

```
//by using Laravel framework    

$images = $request->file('gig-images');

echo count($images); 
//it returns only 1 file while I upload multiple files

exit;
```

Comment: Where are files uploaded to server at `javascript`?

Comment: Files are uploading using php not javascript. I just use javascript for the purpose of validate dimensions and preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with declare the array var img_valid_arr = []; outside the onchange function.

```
        var img_valid_arr = [];
        document.querySelector('#fileee').addEventListener('change', function (){
        var files = this.files;
        var imageBox = document.querySelector('.gig-images-box .box-body');
        var imageBoxFooter = $('.gig-images-box .box-footer');
        //  $('.gig-images-box .box-body').find('img.new_up').remove();


        if (files.length > 0) {

            imageBoxFooter.html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var load_img = new Image();
                load_img.onload = function () {
                    var height = this.height;
                    var width = this.width;
                    if (width == 750 && height == 350) {
                        var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
                        imgElement.className = 'meriimage new_up';
                        imgElement.height = 60;
                        imgElement.src = this.src;
                        imgElement.onload = function () {
                            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(imgElement.src);
                        };
                        imageBox.appendChild(imgElement);
                    } else {
                        img_valid_arr.push('not valid');
                    }

                    var sub = files.length - img_valid_arr.length;

                    console.log(sub);

                    var selc_cont = (sub == 0) ? '<p>No image selected.</p>' : '<p>' + sub + ' image selected.</p>';

                    if (img_valid_arr.length > 0) {
                        imageBoxFooter.append(selc_cont);
                        $('.image-title').append('<span class="help-block" style="color:#ff0000; font-size:12px; display:inline-block">The image dimensions should be: 750 width and 350 height</span>');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('.help-block').fadeOut();
                        }, 3000);
                    } else {
                        imageBoxFooter.html(selc_cont);
                    }
                };
                load_img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
            }
        } else {
            imageBoxFooter.html('');
            imageBoxFooter.html('<p>No image selected.</p>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have comment out that line still only last file goes to the server

Comment: Also I have declared it outside the function, still it shows only last image

Comment: If its multiselect input file element or not?

Comment: did You select one after one or 2 or more image at on time?

Comment: <input name="gig-images[]" accept="image/*" type="file" multiple id="fileee">

Comment: the thing is select multiple image at one time. because 'multiple' selecting the files at one time only. If you JS, you can select one after one and its preview

Comment: Yes you are right. thank you, you saved my time. But one thing is can we upload one by one image with preview then submit all the preview images?

Comment: How? will you guide me little bit?

Comment: rajaunleashed@gmail.com kindly send me the code pls